# ios navigation routing through URL schemas

Tags: ios, schema, ios7

Good evening fellas,

I was looking for a routing api to help me navigate through my app using urls. for Instance If I get a schema in a notification to show the user profile I could do someting like /user/profile on the api and get the view controller with the user information.

While searching we found this lib that seems easy enough to use and straight forward 
https://github.com/usepropeller/routable-ios

Yet having one option is like having none. Does anyone have any other libraries to suggest so that we can test (play) with them and stay with the one that is most valuable?

Regards,

LSonic

Comment: https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes

Comment: [ABRouter](https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/ABRouter) and [HHRouter](https://github.com/Huohua/HHRouter) are alternatives worth checking out

Comment: It's alright. I had to eventually write my own, Post it as an answer though.

Comment: Did you eventually write your own? i'm interrested to see what you come up with, since i'm struggling with the same problem right now.